# How to change iOS simulator on Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

How can I change default iOS simulator on Visual Studio for Mac?

When I pair my MacBook with PC, I have a list of iOS simulators available in Visual Studio 2019 ( on Windows). But when I work directly on MacBook, and run Visual Studio for Mac, there's only one (grayed) simulator available and I have no idea how to change it. Checked Solution options, Project settings. But there's no option to change it.

It looks like that now:

[image: default-ios-simulator]

How can I fix this issue?

---

UPDATE #1

Probably this information could help. Some time ago my XCode and Visual Studio were automatically updated to 12.3 and I start getting errors related to missing developer profile. I uninstalled XCode 12.3 and Visual Studio and installed previous versions. Now XCode version is 12.2 and the error message related to the developer profile is gone. Maybe it somehow connected to the issue I have.

- Current XCode version: 12.2 (12B45b)
- Visual Studio for Mac version:
  8.8.4 (build 30)
- Operating system: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

---

UPDATE #2

I've updated MacOS to version Big Sur
Also I have uninstalled XCode and installed again version 12.3
And I've uninstalled Visual Studio for Mac and installed it again.

The problem still persists.

---

UPDATE #3

Below, there is information about versions:

- Operating system: **MacOS Big Sur, version 11.1**
- XCode version: **12.3 (12c33)**
- Visual Studio For Mac, **version 8.8.6 (Build 15)**
- Xamarin.iOS: 6.18.0.23 (d16-6/088c73638). Package Version: 612000113
- Minimum system version (in Info.plist): **11.0**

Comment: Can you provide the installed versions for 
mac OS, VS for mac, Xamarin.iOS, XCode

Comment: Also what is your minimum iOS version in info.plist

Comment: @HammadShabbir I have updated my question, check `Update 3`

Comment: You still haven't written Xamarin.iOS version

Comment: @HammadShabbir I posted Xamarin version. Or do you mean iOS version on iPhone simulator?

Comment: There would be a Xamarin.iOs version specified in VS for mac about section

Comment: @HammadShabbir Xamarin.iOS: 6.18.0.23 (d16-6/088c73638). Package Version: 612000113

Comment: update your xamarin.ios version to latest version i-e 14.8 which is compatible to xcode 12.3

Comment: Will you please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/frameworks/uitest/ios/simulator?tabs=vsmac)

Comment: @RakshaSaini thank you, Raksha. In XCode, according to the article, I have a list of simulators, and there are many of them. Moreover, on the paired PC with Windows, I can select any simulator, that displayed in XCode on Mac. But on Visual Studio for Mac there is only one simualtor present and it is grayed, and I can't change it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reproduce this issue on my mac. You could follow the stpes below.

1. Open the XCode. Click Window tab to open the Device and Simulators.
2. Click Simulators on left side. Then Click + at the bottom left to create a new eimulator.
3. After that close and restart the VS.

And now, you could use the ios simulators.

Comment: thank you, but this did not solve my issue. In the XCode I have a big list of simulators available.Anyway I have added a new simulator (iPhone 6s). Then closed XCode and Visual Studio, and then launched XCode and Visual Studio. The problem persists. XCode version is 12.2.

Comment: I have updated my question, probably this information could help.

Comment: Normally, the simulators would sync with the list in VS. You could update the XCode to the lastes version and close all of them. Restart the computer it would fix this issue.

Comment: In case I update XCode when I try to deploy app to the simulator (not the actual device), I start getting error, related to missing developer profile. For this reason I have installed XCode 12.2, that does not have this error displayed upon working with simulator.

Comment: For now, could you get the list of simulators?

Comment: Full list of ios-simulators is available only on paired PC. When I run Visual Studio for Mac on the MacBook only the grayed option available, as I stated in the question. In the XCode options I see many simulators listed, but in Visual Studio for Mac only one grayed option, and I can't expand this option to select another simulator.

Comment: I've updated MacOS, XCode and Visual Studio, but the problem still persists (check Update #2 in my question).

Comment: I Just disconected of mac e conect again and the new devices showing for me.